ARCH-Vasicek model closed-form solution
I understand how we can obtain the solution of Vasicek model $dr_t=\alpha(\mu-r_t)dt+\sigma dW_t$:
$$
r_t=r_0e^{-\alpha t}+\mu(1-e^{-\alpha t})+\sigma\int_0^te^{-\alpha(t-s)dW_{s}}
$$
This easily allows me to find $\mathbb{E}[r_t]$ and $Var[r_t]$.
However, I am stuck with following ARCH-Vasicek discrete equations. What I'm trying to do is write the model in continuous form and find its closed-form solution to get the expectation and variance of $r_t$.
$$
\Delta r_t=\alpha(\mu-r_{t-1})\Delta t+\epsilon_t \\
\epsilon_t = \sqrt{\sigma^2_t}u_t, u_t \to iid(0,1)\\
\sigma^2_t=\omega+b_1\epsilon^2_{t-1} \\
\alpha>o
$$
I'm not so good at stochastic calculus. Any help would be appreciated.

Should the first line in your discrete equations read: $\Delta r_{t} = \alpha(\mu - r_{t-1})\Delta t + \varepsilon_{t}$? And are there parameter restrictions on $\alpha, \mu, b_{1}, \omega$?
